# Problem with using Python library - Pyotodom

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I wanted to use [this](https://github.com/limebrains/pyotodom) library to scrape data from otodom. I've read the docs however I'm stuck on a very basic level, trying to do basic import. The code I use is taken directly from the docs. On top of that I've tried to launch example.py from Github but I'm getting the same error.

Here's the excerpt from the code:

```
import otodom, os, logging
from otodom.category import get_category
from otodom.offer import get_offer_information
```

Error message I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File ".\otodom_import.py", line 2, in
>
> from otodom.category import get_category
>
> File "C:\Users\Dom\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\otodom\category.py", line 9, in
>
> from otodom.utils import get_response_for_url, get_url
>
> File "C:\Users\Dom\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\otodom\utils.py", line 14, in
>
> from scrapper_helpers.utils import caching, normalize_text, key_sha1, 
>       get_random_user_agent
>
> File "C:\Users\Dom\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapper_helpers\utils.py", 
>     line 22, in
>
> MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH = subprocess.check_output("getconf NAME_MAX /", 
>       shell=True).strip()
>
> File "C:\Users\Dom\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
>       **kwargs).stdout
>
> File "C:\Users\Dom\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 418, in run
>       output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
>
> subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'getconf NAME_MAX /' returned non-zero 
>     exit status 1.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Don't understand downvotes, I realize that this is a niche module but I did my homework. I've read the docs and tried to find help in other places. If there is a chance that as a noobie I'll find at least one person that can help me, why wouldn't I use this opportunity? Even info that module is buggy can help.

Answer (score 0):

[`getconf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getconf.html), which the dependency [`scrapper_helpers`](https://github.com/limebrains/scrapper-helpers) module is trying to call, is a POSIX command not available on Windows.

You can track it down in `C:\Users\Dom\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapper_helpers\utils.py` and replace the line 22 with:

```
MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH = 255
```

But then the question is what other error might pop up given that the module obviously expects to run on a POSIX-compatible system - for example, it will attempt to use `/var/tmp/scrapper-helpers/` as its temporary cache path which is also not available on Windows (but Python will interpret it as `<DRIVE_LETTER>:\var\tmp\scrapper-helpers` and attempt to create it).

Alternatively, looking at its code, you might get away with just declaring the following environment variables:

```
set MAX_FILENAME_LENGTH=255
set CACHE_DIR=%TEMP%\scapper-helpers\
```

Comment: Ok, so it's seems that fixing it is out of my reach at the moment since I'm a beginner. Would changing operating system help? Which should I use instead of Windows?

Comment: @PiotrMenclewicz - [Declaring environment variables](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) is rather easy but if you don't want to deal with that, Linux is POSIX compatible so pick whichever distro you prefer. MacOS X is also POSIX compatible.